# Chrome opening links after prefixing with another domain

Tags: google-chrome, malware, malware-detection

So, I was browsing through Chrome for something around three days ago in Google, and when I clicked a search result, noticed a weird think happening in the URL bar. Generally, clicking a link shown in Google search results, let's say `abc.com/somewebpagehere` should lead me directly to that webpage. But, I saw that instead of taking me directly to that website, I was seeing this right after clicking the search results:

[image]

The URL was being prefixed by `go.lnkam.com` instead of google.com which we generally see. Searching on the web tells me that this is a malware issue, ran a full scan using Windows Defender but could locate none. Can someone suggest something better?

(P.S.: I've not checked whether this issue persists in other browsers or not, I rarely use them)

Comment: Have you tried what's described at this link https://malwaretips.com/blogs/remove-go-lnkam-com/ If you need to reset the browser, try another step before by disabling some extensions.

Comment: This problem doesn't appear all the time, I see it sometimes. At other times, chrome behaves normally. and yes, I  have tried the one you linked to